# Using declaration in class refers into 'std::', which is not a class

Tags: c++, class, namespaces, std, using-declaration

I'm trying to unlearn `using namespace std`, considering https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MZqjl9HEPZ8

So I tried

```
// using namespace std;

struct Data
{
    using std::shared_ptr;
    
    shared_ptr<char[]> m_name = nullptr;
    
//    std::shared_ptr<char[]> m_name = nullptr;
};
```

And from that I got

> main.cpp:14:11: Using declaration in class refers into 'std::', which is not a class

It seems I cannot do `using std::shared_ptr;` inside class declaration?

Am I missing something or really need to type `std::shared_ptr` there?

Comment: you *can* do a template alias, but imo it should be `std::shared_ptr` in this case.

Comment: Define your types like using shared_name = std::shared_ptr<char[]>;

Comment: What's wrong with just typing `std::shared_ptr<char[]` ? Side note : I really would advise you to use std::shared_ptr<std::string> in this case (assuming the shared_ptr is really necessary, which a lot of the time it isn't)

Comment: Nothing wrong, but would be cool if we could just type `shared_ptr<char[]`, preceded by `using std::shared_ptr;`

Comment: Would it, though? That's very much an early learner sentiment. That sentiment changes quite a bit as you continue on and your projects get to be complex. `std::` is nothing.

Answer (score 1):

From the C++ 17 Standard (10.3.3 The using declaration)

> 3 **In a using-declaration used as a member-declaration, each
> using-declarator’s nested-name-specifier shall name a base class of
> the class being defined.** If a using-declarator names a constructor,
> its nested-name-specifier shall name a direct base class of the class
> being defined.

`std::shared_ptr` is not a member of a base class of the class `Data` in your code example.

So the compiler issues an error.

`std:;shared_ptr` is a class declared in the namespace `std`. It is not even a member of some class.

Answer (score 1):

Certain forms of `using` don't work in class bodies. This includes `using namespace` and `using X` where `X` isn't inherited from the base class.

`using std::shared_ptr;` works if you move it to the global scope.

`using X = Y;` does work at class scope. In your case, it would be `template <typename T> using shared_ptr = std::shared_ptr<T>;`. But note that in rare cases it's slightly different from spelling it as `std::shared_ptr` (e.g. when passing it to template template parameters).

---

> [do I] really need to type `std::shared_ptr` there?

You *should* type `std::shared_ptr`. Omitting `std::` often causes confusion. "Is it something from `std::` or something custom?"